# People can see how people from different places live their lives and compare it with their own lifestyles

Tags: sentence-construction

Does this sentence look natural to native speaker? Is there any other better way to rephrase this sentence. I feel my sentence is a Little redundant

Answer (score 1):

Repetition like this very rarely looks/sounds right in prose, and even in poetry and song only the sounds normally repeat, rather than specific words.

I would probably write this as: `[Specific people] can see how people from different places live their lives ...`
Where the square brackets might be `Londoners`, `Southerners`, `Foreigners` or something appropriate to your specific scenario.

Comment: Shouldn't it be _compare them_ (other people's lives)?

Comment: @KateBunting  Yes, you are right - I missed that bit. Could easily still have been `it` if the first half had been re-written differently of course.

Answer (score -2):

You could substitute `people from different place` with an appropriate term like `foreigner` or `outsider`.

*People can compare the lifestyle with their counterparts whom they consider foreign or strange.*

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!